# Jenkins add Git Behaviors using groovy scripts

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm creating my Jenkins instance using groovy scripts because I'm automating the Jenkins creation process. I create this script:

```
/* Adds a multibranch pipeline job to Jenkins */
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.PersistedList
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.branch.*
import jenkins.model.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import jenkins.plugins.git.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.*

// Create job
def env = System.getenv()
Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.instance
String jobName = "Job"
String jobScript = "Jenkinsfile"
def job = jenkins.getItem(jobName)

// Create the folder if it doesn't exist
if (job == null) {
  job = jenkins.createProject(WorkflowMultiBranchProject.class, jobName)
}
job.getProjectFactory().setScriptPath(jobScript)

// Add git repo
String id = null
String remote = env.CODE_COMMIT_URL
String includes = "*"
String excludes = ""
boolean ignoreOnPushNotifications = false
GitSCMSource gitSCMSource = new GitSCMSource(id, remote, null, includes, excludes, ignoreOnPushNotifications)
BranchSource branchSource = new BranchSource(gitSCMSource)

// Remove and replace?
PersistedList sources = job.getSourcesList()
sources.clear()
sources.add(branchSource)
job.addTrigger(new PeriodicFolderTrigger("1m"))
```

and paste it at `$JENKINS_HOME/ref/init.groovy.d/`. When I start Jenkins, by job was already created. Besides that, I need to add some Git Behaviors to my job and I'd like to know if is there a way to add Git Behaviors using groovy script?

My Git after created:

[image]

Git behaviors I'd like to add at initialization (Discover tags, Check out to matching local branch, Custom user name/e-mail address)

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is managed through traits (I haven't actually tried this):

```
import jenkins.plugins.git.traits.*

def traits = []
// Add your traits...
traits.add(new TagDiscoveryTrait())
traits.add(new LocalBranchTrait())
gitSCMSource.setTraits(traits)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. I also have added `traits.add(new UserIdentityTrait(new UserIdentity(username, email)))`